# Improve performance of SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to improve the performance of a stored procedure that is used by SSRS. When a very narrow set of parameters are passed, the stored procedure completes rather quickly. But when more than a hundred thousand results are returned, the stored procedure takes minutes to run.

For example, if I run this using the date range of 1982 - 2020, it takes 15 minutes to run and returns 180000 records.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[uspContractFundingbyYear2]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
drop procedure [dbo].[uspContractFundingbyYear2]
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      J. Dickens
-- Create date: April 2011
-- Description: This SP generates contract funding records for the selected parameters.
--              Each row should represent a single contract funding record. 
--              In many cases, either 0 or 100 is used to designate an option that is not selected. The parameter should have no impact on the query. 
--              Otherwise all values are passed to the parameter using the multivalue parameter function.
-- =============================================

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspContractFundingbyYear2]
    @StartYear datetime
    ,@EndYear datetime
    ,@BusinessEntityID  nvarchar(max)
    ,@ContractTypeCode nvarchar(max)
    ,@ContractStatusCode nvarchar(max)
    ,@ContractOrgID nvarchar(max)
    ,@ResearchTypeCode nvarchar(max)
    ,@ExportControlLevelCode nvarchar(max)
    ,@ScienceAreaID nvarchar(max)
    ,@ThrustAreaID nvarchar (max)
    ,@ContractStartdate datetime
    ,@ContractEnddate datetime
    ,@ResearchBusID int
    ,@MasterContractOnlyFlag bit
    ,@StateProvinceCode nvarchar(max)
    ,@CountryID nvarchar(max)
    ,@FinalYearFlag int
    ,@CollaborativeDollars int
    ,@SubcontractsFlag int
    ,@FundingOrgID nvarchar(max)
    ,@FundingTypeCode nvarchar(max)
    ,@FundingStatusCode nvarchar(max)
    ,@FundingStartdate datetime
    ,@FundingEnddate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --- Prepare a table of Year Numbers, for use with Cross Join
    DECLARE @Dates TABLE (YearNo INT) 

    ;WITH n(n) AS
    (
        SELECT YEAR(@StartYear)
        UNION ALL

        SELECT n+1 
        FROM n 
        WHERE n < YEAR(@EndYear)
    )
    INSERT INTO @Dates(YearNo)
        SELECT n 
        FROM n 
        ORDER BY n

    -- Now find all the contract funding records 
    select distinct
        be.BusinessEntityName 
        , Q.ScienceArea
        , r.ResearchBusID
        , c.FormattedBusID
        , o.Abbreviation as 'ContractOrg'
        , c.StateProvinceCode
        , cy.CountryName
        , cf.ContractFundingID
        , c.ContractTypeCode
        , c.ContractID,
        , [Thrust] = dbo.ufConcatenateThrustsforResTaskDate (r.ResearchID, NULL, NULL, NULL)
        , [PI] = (select STUFF((select distinct(coalesce('; '+P.lastfirst,''))
    from ResTaskParticipant rtp
    join PersonOrg po on rtp.PersonOrgID = po.PersonOrgID
    join Person p on po.PersonID = p.PersonID
    where rtp.ResearchID = r.researchid
      and rtp.ParticipantTypeCode = 'PI'
      and (rtp.enddate > getdate() or rtp.enddate = r.enddate)
    for XML path ('')),1,2,'')),
c.ContractStatusCode,
cf.Fundingstatuscode as 'FundingStatus', cf.FundingTypeCode as 'FundingType', cf.Funding, 
o2.Abbreviation as 'FundingSourceOrg',  cf.StartDate, cf.EndDate,
DATEDIFF(m,cf.StartDate, dateadd(d,2,cf.EndDate)) as 'ContractMonths', --using 2 days here to allow for leap years
[BurnRate] =
case  
when DATEDIFF(m,cf.StartDate, dateadd(d,2,cf.EndDate))  = 0 --using 2 days here to allow for leap years
then convert(decimal(2,1), 0)
else
 convert(decimal (15,5), convert(decimal(15,0),cf.Funding)/convert(decimal(2,0),(DATEDIFF(m,cf.StartDate, dateadd(d,2,cf.EndDate)))))  --using 2 days here to allow for leap years
end
, [IsFirstOfMonth] = 
case when  cf.startdate = (select FirstDayofMonth from dbo.ufGetFirstLastDayofMonth(cf.StartDate, 0)) then 1 else 0 end
, [IsEndOfMonth] = 
case when  datepart(day,cf.EndDate) = datepart(day,(select LastDayofMonth from dbo.ufGetFirstLastDayofMonth(cf.EndDate, 0))) then 1 else 0 end
, [MonthsInYear] = Convert(decimal(2,0), (select dbo.ufmonthsincontractforyear (cf.startdate, cf.EndDate, d.YearNo)))
,[YearNo] =  d.YearNo


from ContractFunding cf 
join Contract c  on cf.ContractID = c.ContractID
join Research r on c.ResearchID = r.ResearchID
join BusinessEntity be on r.BusinessEntityID = be.BusinessEntityID
join Organization o on c.OrganizationID = o.OrganizationID --Contract Org
join Country cy on c.CountryID = cy.CountryID  
join Organization o2 on cf.SourceOrganizationID = o2.OrganizationID --Funding Org
left outer join TaskFunding tf on cf.ContractFundingID = tf.ContractFundingID

--Get the range of years for each Contract Funding row
cross join @Dates d 

--get Science Area
cross apply (select [ScienceArea]  = dbo.ufConcatenateScienceAreasforResTaskDate (r.ResearchID, NULL, NULL, NULL)) as  Q


where
-- required parameters for running report are Start and End Years
cf.StartDate <= @EndYear and cf.EndDate >= @StartYear

-- now all the bells and whistles
and r.BusinessEntityID in (select val from [dbo].[ufStringToTable] (@BusinessEntityID,',',1))
and c.ContractTypeCode in (select val from [dbo].[ufStringToTable] (@ContractTypeCode,',',1))
and c.ContractStatusCode in (select val from [dbo].[ufStringToTable] (@ContractStatusCode,',',1))
and c.OrganizationID in (select val from dbo.ufStringToTable (@ContractOrgID,',',1))
and (@ResearchTypeCode = '0' or (r.ResearchTypeCode in (select val from dbo.ufStringToTable (@ResearchTypeCode,',',1))))
and (@ExportControlLevelCode = '100' or c.ExportControlLevelCode = @ExportControlLevelCode)

-- For Science Area Funding, of the set of Contract Funding records returned, select those that match the given Science Area
and (@ScienceAreaID = '0' or (cf.ScienceAreaID in (select val from dbo.ufStringToTable (@ScienceAreaID,',',1)))) 

-- For Thrust Area Funding, of the set of Contract Funding records returned, select those that match the given Thrust Area
and (@ThrustAreaID = '0' or (tf.ThrustAreaID in (select val from dbo.ufStringToTable (@ThrustAreaID,',',1))))

-- Find Contracts within given "Active" dates
and (
        (@ContractStartdate is null and @ContractEnddate is null)
        OR
        (c.enddate > @ContractStartdate and c.StartDate <=@ContractEnddate)
        or
        (@ContractStartdate is null and c.StartDate <=@ContractEnddate)
        or
        (c.EndDate > @ContractStartdate and @ContractEnddate is null)
    )
and (@ResearchBusID = '' or r.ResearchBusID = @ResearchBusID)
and (@MasterContractOnlyFlag = 0  or (@MasterContractOnlyFlag = 1 and c.MasterContractFlag = 1))
and (@StateProvinceCode = '0' or (c.StateProvinceCode in (select val from dbo.ufStringToTable (@StateProvinceCode,',',1))))

and c.CountryID in (select val from dbo.ufStringToTable (@CountryID,',',1)) --Not all contracts have a country assignment
and (@FinalYearFlag = 100 
    or 
    (@FinalYearFlag = 0 and (dbo.ufContractIsInFinalYear(c.contractid,getdate()) = 0))
    or
    (@FinalYearFlag = 1 and (dbo.ufContractIsInFinalYear(c.contractid,GETDATE()) = 1))
    )

and (@CollaborativeDollars = 100
    or 
    (@CollaborativeDollars = 0 and 
        not exists 
            (select * from ContractFunding cf2 where cf2.FundingTypeCode='Collaborative' and cf2.ContractID=c.ContractID)
        )
    or 
    (@CollaborativeDollars = 1 and 
        exists 
            (select * from ContractFunding cf2 where cf2.FundingTypeCode='Collaborative' and cf2.ContractID=c.ContractID)
        )
    )
and (@SubcontractsFlag = 100
    or 
    (@SubcontractsFlag = 0 and c.SubContractFlag = 0)
    or
    (@SubcontractsFlag = 1 and c.SubContractFlag = 1)
    )

and (cf.SourceOrganizationID in (select val from dbo.ufStringToTable (@FundingOrgID,',',1)))

and (cf.FundingTypeCode in (select val from dbo.ufStringToTable (@FundingTypeCode,',',1)))

and (cf.FundingStatusCode in (select val from dbo.ufStringToTable (@FundingStatusCode,',',1)))
and (
        (@FundingStartdate is null and @FundingEnddate is null)
        OR
        (c.enddate > @FundingStartdate and c.StartDate <=@FundingEnddate)
        or
        (@FundingStartdate is null and c.StartDate <=@FundingEnddate)
        or
        (c.EndDate > @FundingStartdate and @FundingEnddate is null)
    )


End
GO
```

Comment: Examine the execution plan, look at the indexes you have, UDF calls in where clauses is a common killer.

Comment: Distinct and order by are both expensive operations, so there is that.

Comment: agh. my eyes. they burn. No simple way to optimize this as there are several hidden performance killers in here: concatenating text using XML and stuff, cross apply with a function which forces row by row processing, columnar sub queries that reference a UDF. The short story is that your query is performaing A LOT of row by row processing, so the more rows the slower it will get.

Comment: Those scalar functions are killing you here. I suspect that one of them the usStringToTable is converting a delimited string to a table? Are there loops inside that function? There are ways to deal with delimited strings. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings You have several other scalar functions. You also have a catch-all type of query here that could be improved. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/ The biggest issue is you posted a big query and said "It's slow, help me" but you didn't post the tables, indexes or many details at all.

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you for the constructive feedback and links to read. How do I post the tables and indexes? 
I figured that the "StringToTable" calls were creating a problem. Historically I would just send a 0 to the SP rather than passing all values, but it makes for a more crude interface in SSRS. (When you create a fake "Select All" option in SSRS, you get the SSRS default "Select All" and then your fake "Select All" or "Default" choice.)

Comment: "Prepare a table of Year Numbers, for use with Cross Join" ... create an actual table of dates (i.e. a Date Dimension in data warehouse terms), so you don't have to build one on the fly every time. The PK would be an integer value of the date (i.e. 20151104). Convert your date parameters to an integer of the same format (i.e. Start Date = 20150101, End Date = 20151031). Then, use a CTE to get all dates (rows) between StartDate and EndDate and use that in your cross join. Our data warehouse uses dates like this, and the Integers are just so much faster in WHERE and JOIN clauses.

Comment: You could post the sql statements to create the tables and indexes. "Create table....." The same way you posted the procedure. You should also post those functions.